# adobe air android project xml change automatic

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I need to make changes in the file project android manifest xml for android.
But when I write permission and other and click publish button on adobe flash all the changes replace by default !
I active checkbox  manually on air android setting .
this is my code to need inser  to xml file :

```
<permission android:name="{APP-PACKAGE-NAME}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
            <uses-permission android:name="{APP-PACKAGE-NAME}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: This has happened to me before. Make sure you are modifying the descriptor file that is in the 'src' folder and not the onde in the bin-debug one. You can also try to run the clean tool on your project.

Comment: thank you . but <permission.... > is not correct in line 1 and i change it by  <uses-permission ..... and fixed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<permission.... >` is not correct in line 1 and i change it by `<uses-permission>` ..... and fixed !